# boot-repair live session message

Tags: boot-repair

I rebooted ubuntu 18.04 and the first thing I did was start boot-repair. I took the option to repair most common problems. I get "Please use this software in a live-session (live-CD or live-USB). This will enable this feature."

What does this mean? How do I run it to rebuild boot ?

I booted from hard disk, not CD or USB

Comment: boot-repair seems to have lost my Windows boot option. I no longer get any boot options - 18.04 just starts up every time. I ran Grub-repair but it's not functioning properly; gets 3/4 way through loading, then hangs. I'll look at it later. For now my system does what I need it to do

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the message means, but I booted from USB, installed boot-repair and ran it. This time I did not get the error message. Afterwards the system successfully booted from the HD.